# Apache/PHP writing to a user's home folder

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

I have created an SSH user on our system, `fred`, whose home directory is `/home/fred` and who has a subdirectory at `/home/fred/someFolder`. I am trying to allow PHP/Apache, which is running as `nobody`, to be able to create a file inside fred's `someFolder` directory. No matter what I try, I always get `Warning: file_put_contents(/home/fred/someFolder/test.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/websiteDir/public_html/test.php on line 1`

I have tried several different ways of doing this and nothing seems to work so far. Tried to chmod the folder to 777, 666, 660, etc. Tried chown with fred:nobody, nobody:fred, nobody:nobody, fred:fred, still nothing. Tried adding fred to nobody's group, tried adding nobody to fred's group, nada.

Sorry, I'm not all that great at linux... any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: can you run `ls -lha` in /home/fred/someFolder and post it up here?

Comment: `total 8.0K
drw-rw---- 2 nobody    fred 4.0K Feb 14 11:15 ./
drwx--x--x 5 fred      fred 4.0K Feb 14 11:15 ../`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All parent directories of /home/fred/someFolder must have the execute bit set for the user/group accessing it. So most likely /home/fred is missing this. `chmod a+x /home/fred`

Comment: I have done that and still receive the same error.

Comment: From looking at your comment on gravyface's question, youre missing the execute bit on 'someFolder'. All folders must have the execute bit set, or theyre pretty much useless.

Comment: Ah, that finally did it. When you said 'parent directories' I wasn't thinking about the actual one I needed, only the ones above it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thats ok, I didnt expect the execute bit to be missing from it as it should be there by default on all newely created directories.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether SELinux is running in Enforcing mode. If so, it can cause permissions issues that don't appear to be supported by the actual UNIX file permissions you're seeing and setting. You can use `getenforce` (at least on Redhat/CentOS) to see the state of SELinux, and `setenforce 0` to disable it interactively. In order to have the change persist, you'll need to edit the SELinux configuration in `/etc/selinux/config`. Hope that helps!

Comment: getenforce seems to already be disabled.